# Remove first space in string using Haskell

Tags: haskell

How do I remove the first space of a string in Haskell?

For example:

```
removeSpace " hello" = "hello"

removeSpace "  hello" = " hello"

removeSpace "hello" = "hello"
```

Comment: Do you want to remove only one space at the start of the string, all spaces at the start of the string, or the first space in the string even if it's not the first character in the string?

Comment: I don't know exactly what this guy wants, but the second example here clearly shows that this question is not identical to the claimed duplicate. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Absolutely. That question's about using Text functions on String values. That answer won't help user1836399 much!

Answer (score 12):

Here are multiple remove-space options, to show of a few functions and ways of doing things.

To take multiple spaces, you can do

```
removeSpaces = dropWhile (==' ')
```

This means the same as `removeSpaces xs = dropWhile (==' ') xs`, but uses partial application (and so does `(==' ')` in essence).

or for more general removal,

```
import Data.Char
removeWhitespace = dropWhile isSpace
```

If you're really sure you just want to take one space (and you certainly seem to be), then pattern matching is clearest:

```
removeASpace (' ':xs) = xs  -- if it starts with a space, miss that out.
removeASpace xs = xs        -- otherwise just leave the string alone
```

This works because in haskell, `String = [Char]` and `(x:xs)` means the list that starts with `x` and carries on with the list `xs`.

To remove one whitespace character, we can use function guards (if statements with very light syntax, if you've not met them):

```
removeAWhitespace "" = ""  -- base case of empty string
removeAWhitespace (x:xs) | isSpace x = xs   -- if it's whitespace, omit it
                         | otherwise = x:xs -- if it's not keep it.
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply use pattern matching:

```
removeSpace (' ':xs) = xs
removeSpace xs = xs
```

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, strings are simply list of characters, i.e., the Prelude defines

```
type String = [Char]
```

Furthermore, there are about three ways to write a function:

1. Completely roll it yourself using the two most fundamental tools you have at your disposal: pattern matching and recursion;
2. Cleverly combine some already written functions; and, of course
3. A mix of these.

If you are new to Haskell and to functional programming, I recommend writing most of your functions using the first method and then gradually shift toward using more and more predefined functions.

For your problem—removing the first space character (`' '`) in a string—pattern matching and recursion actually make a lot of sense. As said, strings are just lists of characters, so we will end up with nothing but a simple list traversal.

Let us first write a signature for your function:

```
removeSpace :: [Char] -> [Char]
```

(I have written `[Char]` rather than `String` to make it explicit that we are performing a list traversal here.)

Pattern matching against a list, we need to consider two cases: the list being empty (`[]`) and the list consisting of a head element followed by a tail (`c : cs`).

Dealing with the empty list is, as always, simple: there are no characters left, so there is nothing to remove anymore and we simply return the empty list.

```
removeSpace [] = []
```

Then the situation in which we have a head element (a character) and a tail list. Here we need to distinguish two cases again: the case in which the head character is a space and the case in which it is any other character.

If the head character is a space, it will be the first space that we encounter and we need to remove it. As we only have to remove the first space, we can return the remainder of the list (i.e., the tail) without further processing:

```
removeSpace (' ' : cs) = cs
```

What remains is to deal with the case in which the head character is not a space. Then we need to keep it in the returned list and, moreover, we need to keep seeking for the first space in the remainder of the list; that is, we need to recursively apply our function to the tail:

```
removeSpace (c : cs) = c : removeSpace cs
```

And that's all. The complete definition of our function now reads

```
removeSpace :: [Char]     -> [Char]
removeSpace    []         =  []
removeSpace    (' ' : cs) =  cs
removeSpace    (c   : cs) =  c : removeSpace cs
```

This is arguably as clear and concise a definition as any clever combining of predefined functions would have given you.

To wrap up, let us test our function:

```
> removeSpace " hello"
"hello"

> removeSpace "  hello"
" hello"

> removeSpace "hello"
"hello"
```

If you really want construct your function out of predefined functions, here is one alternative definition of `removeSpace` that will do the trick:

```
removeSpace :: [Char] -> [Char]    
removeSpace =  uncurry (flip (flip (++) . drop 1)) . break (== ' ')
```

(You can see why I prefer the one using explicit pattern matching and recursion. ;-))

**Note:** *I have assumed that your objective is indeed to remove the first space in a string, no matter where that first space appears. In the examples you have given, the first space is always the first character in the string. If that's always the case, i.e., if you are only after dropping a leading space, you can leave out the recursion and simply write*

```
removeSpace :: [Char]     -> [Char]
removeSpace    []         =  []
removeSpace    (' ' : cs) =  cs
removeSpace    (c   : cs) =  c : cs
```

*or, combining the first and last cases,*

```
removeSpace :: [Char]     -> [Char]
removeSpace    (' ' : cs) =  cs
removeSpace    cs         =  cs
```

*or, using predefined functions,*

```
removeSpace :: [Char] -> [Char]
removeSpace =  uncurry ((++) . drop 1) . span (== ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first space anywhere in a string:

```
removeSpace :: String -> String
removeSpace = (\(xs,ys) -> xs ++ drop 1 ys) . span (/=' ')
```

Where `span` grabs characters until it finds a space or reaches the end of the string.

It then splits the results and puts them in a tuple that we take and combine, skipping the first character in the second list (the space). Additionally we assert that the remainder is not `null` (an empty list) - if it is, we can't get the tail as an empty list can't have a tail can it? So if it is, we just return an empty list.

Comment: Note that `if null ys then [] else tail ys` can simply be written as `drop 1 ys`. Hence: `removeSpace = (\(xs,ys) -> xs ++ drop 1 ys) . span (/=' ')`.